# complete background moving image in android studio?

Tags: java, android, animation

I am using the following code to move my image from right to left. what I want is to stop image halfway and then reset and I want my image to clone itself and added against each step a full scrolling background from right to left.

```
    ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, -300.0f,0.0f,    0.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
    animation.setDuration(9000);  // animation duration
    animation.setRepeatCount(6);  // animation repeat count
    animation.setRepeatMode(0);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )
    animation.setFillAfter(true);

    img_animation.startAnimation(animation);
```

The problem is that only 1 image moves but I want that image to colone itself and scroll from right to left.